# Distance from a point to a poly line and attributes from the poly line GIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line, distance

I'm trying to figure out what tool would be best to get the distance from multi-points from multi polylines and see which attributes are closest to what point.

I'm doing a project where I have historical tornado data and would like to know what intensity and how close these historic tornados were close to rural schools.

Comment: if I understand question correctly, you need 'Point Distance' tool, where school will be in_features and tornado near_features (or vice versa depending upon the process u want to follow). Put it through a iterator.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will not get to it for another week or so. I will let ya know how it gos.

Comment: point distance doesn't use polylines ?